# convert raw bytes to hexadecimal in c++ or assembly(FASM)

Tags: c++, assembly, io, hex, fasm

I know this sounds like a really dumb question but I am trying to build a simple hexadecimal editor and I can't read the bytes from the file. I use readfile api to read 8kb buffer and then I was going to convert the 8kb to hexadecimal but it gives me sometimes only 4 bytes in reverse order or sometimes 0 I am not sure what I am doing wrong. how can i get it to where it will give me the full 8kb in hex representation. If their is a better way to convert an entire file to hex please let me know. Im just looking for the fastest way to read an entire file and display it on the screen in hexadecimal representation. thanks

FASM syntax but could easily be c++ as well

```
invoke ReadFile, [hFile],filebuffer,8192, BytesWritten, 0 
cinvoke wsprintfA,buffer1,"%X",[filebuffer]
invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,buffer1,title,MB_ICONINFORMATION+MB_OK
```

all data are dd?

**Update**
I marked the second answer as the answe because I found masm syntax assembly that looked like this, and it was really fast, but I went ahead and went with CryptBinaryToString api
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379887

here is fasm syntax assembly code but again could easily become c++

```
invoke ReadFile, [hFile],filebuffer,500, BytesWritten, 0
        push    dwBuffLen
        push    pszHexBuffer
        push    0x0000000b  ; CRYPT_STRING_HEXASCIIADDR
        push    500
        push    filebuffer
        call    [CryptBinaryToStringA]
;pszHexBuffer contains the data

data sections
filebuffer rb 500
BUF_LEN       = 4000
        pszHexBuffer  db BUF_LEN   dup(0)  ; will contain converted bytes in hex. Twice the size of the original buffer at least (Read documentation about the last _In_Out parameter)
        dwBuffLen     dd BUF_LEN
```

Comment: That's not like any C++ I have seen.  It vaguely resembles so-called "threaded macro" assembly from PDP-11 from the late 1970s.

Comment: I know it is assembly but it could just as easily be c++ because its just api calls

Comment: @DarrinWoolit You could forego the `printf` ideology and dump the *nibbles* using a lookup table. That would probably be closer to what you want anyway. It would require a table of 16 chars (the chars `'0'` through `'F'`) and a iterative dump, splitting each octet into two 4-bit nibbles, then using each nibble as an index into the table to know which char to dump. That's how I've done it in the past, anyway. No need to use a sledge hammer like `printf` to swat a fly (though it is, obviously, easier to implement). Note this assumes an 8-bit `char` type to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something a bit more do it yourself style, but this should do the trick.

```
inline char nibble_decode(char nibble)
{
    const char byte_map[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    return byte_map[nibble];
}

char *hex_string(char *buffer, unsigned char *bytes, int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        buffer[i*3] = nibble_decode(bytes[i] >> 4);
        buffer[i*3+1] = nibble_decode(bytes[i] & 0x0f);
        buffer[i*3+2] = ' ';
    }
    buffer[length*3] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Typed this from my phone since I'm on a road trip right now, so I am unable to test this snippet.  Hopefully it conveys the concept though.

In summary it loops through length number of bytes and will use a bit shift for the upper bits and an and operation for the lower bits.  I also added a space but that should be easy to remove if you don't want it.
Note: You must preallocate 3*length+1 bytes to buffer.

Comment: `const char byte_map[16] = "0123456789abcdef";` or `char *byte_map = "0123456789abcdef"` is much shorter

Comment: True.  It could even be inlined complete and indexed directly.  Not sure why I bothered to type it out. Must have been extra bored.

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf("%X")` will only convert a single integer for you, and even that will be done according to little endian (hence the reversing) and without leading zeroes (hence the sometimes shorter output). You will want a loop and print each byte using `%02x` format.

Comment: their is no way i can convert all 8192 bytes at the same time? Im just looking for the fastest way to rad an entire file and display it on the screen in hexadecimal representation